# users with greater than 1 device group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table and what I am looking for is users having greater than one device group by device group.

for e.g.

- for android user_id 1 and 3 has >1 distinct device group.
- for iOS
  user_id 2, 3 and 4 has >1 distinct device group.
- for fireTV user_id
  1, 2 has >1 distinct device group.

Table:

```
*----------------------*
|user_id | device_grp  |
*----------------------*
|    1   |    android  |
|    1   |    fireTV   |  
|    2   |    iOS      |
|    2   |    fireTV   |
|    3   |    android  |
|    3   |    iOS      |
|    4   |    web-play |
|    4   |    iOS      |
|    5   |    android  |
*----------------------*
```

final result:

```
*--------------------------------------*
| device_group | users >1 device_grp   |
*--------------------------------------*
|   android    |    2                  |
|   iOS        |    3                  |
|   fireTV     |    2                  |
|   web-play   |    1                  |
*--------------------------------------*
```

here is the **[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=488283bacf9dcd1ac5526f548a2edfe4)** which is getting result, but is there a better way to achieve above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cnt AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) as user_count
  FROM users
)
SELECT device_grp, COUNT(*) AS ttl
FROM cnt 
WHERE user_count > 1
GROUP BY device_grp
```

Comparison of query execution plans in the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b8b78342769fe7aed2f0ea902ae0067a).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
device_grp  as device_group,
COUNT(*) as Total
FROM table
GROUP BY device_grp  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But your example is wrong because `web-play` total is not greater than 1. If you also need `web-play`:

```
SELECT 
device_grp  as device_group,
COUNT(*) as Total
FROM table
GROUP BY device_grp
```

Comment: my example is right for the web-player, which means there is one user  (user_id 4) with web-play who has more than 1 unique device group.

Comment: @zealous if you could update your requirements without need of example, I will glade to update my answer, because if not, I don't understand you requirement. You need unique device group or device group?